# How do I make my ParseQueryAdapter items selectable?

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-parsequeryadapter

Can anyone tell me how to make text items selectable ?

Here is my current adapter code:

```
final ParseQueryAdapter adapter = new ParseQueryAdapter(this, "Prem");
adapter.setTextKey("des");

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.newslistview);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

What is missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ListView`s default choice mode should be set to `CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE` which means it should allow you to select one item. I suppose this could be affecte by `ParseQueryAdapter`s pagination. Try to disable it with [`adapter.setPaginationEnabled(false)`](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQueryAdapter.html#setPaginationEnabled%28boolean%29). Also call [`setChoiceMode()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setChoiceMode%28int%29) manually on your `ListView` to specify it.